# How to avoid flutter page route jank?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two page flutter app. From one page to another I have used `MaterialPageRoute` to make routs

```
Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => ProductList(),
            ),
          );
```

In my `ProductList()` page I have fixed length `List` so I used `ListView()`, in fact this List item is quite heavy. I have used  `ExpandbleList()` in that List I have included product-details/images etc.. ( whenever I made route this whole List build at once ) even though they are `non-async` build it take quite some time to build that `ListView()`, that curse me to face unpleasant frame drop at route. I want to avoid this jank by adding `CircularProgressIndicator()` in intermediate transition of two pages, Is it possible to do? or another methods to avoid this jank ? ,please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Since you wrote that you use a `ListView` which builds everything at once, I suggest you to make use of `ListView.builder()` which ensures that not all entries are built at once but only on demand while scrolling

Comment: Also I'd check on a real device with flutter run --profile or even --release.If the jank is there or not, debug version on the emulator can be quite janky. Even [the docs say this](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes) : **"Application performance can be janky in debug mode. Measure performance in profile mode on an actual device."**

Comment: @kounex I have only 3 List Items,isn't `ListView()` enough